# Armbian can't run script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm not so confident with Linux but, I've installed Armbian recently, and I can't make a script to run.

I have an Orange PI zero, the script that I found did run on Ubuntu server, so I'm fairly sure that that's not the problem. I need this script for restarting the router daily.

Note: I didn't wrote the script, I copied it from a forum that I don't remember now.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Get session key..."
SKEY=curl -s http://192.168.0.1/login.asp | perl -ne 'if(/var SessionKey = (\S+);/) {print
"$1\n";}' echo "Login... ($SKEY)" curl -X POST -d "loginUsername=admin&loginPassword=<PASSWORD GOES HERE>&loginOrInitDS=0"
http://192.168.0.1/goform/login?sessionKey=$SKEY echo "Get session new key..." SKEY=curl -s
http://192.168.0.1/RgSetup.asp | perl -ne 'if(/var SessionKey = (\S+);/) {print "$1\n";}' echo "Issue reboot...
($SKEY)" curl "http://192.168.0.1/goform/RgSetup?sessionKey=$SKEY" \
        -H 'Referer: http://192.168.0.1/RgSetup.asp' \
        --data 'WanLeaseAction=0&ApplyRgSetupAction=0&RebootAction=1' exit 1
```

I removed the password for this post, but that's not the problem. Anyways. 
Here's the console:

```
root@orangepizero:~# ./router.sh
Get session key...
./router.sh: 3: ./router.sh: -s: not found
Can't open echo: No such file or directory.
Can't open Login... (): No such file or directory.
Can't open curl: No such file or directory.
Can't open -X: No such file or directory.
Can't open POST: No such file or directory.
Can't open -d: No such file or directory.
Can't open loginUsername=admin&loginPasswosmierd=<PASSWORD GOES HERE>&loginOrInitDS=0: No such file or directory.
./router.sh: 5: ./router.sh: http://192.168.0.1/goform/login?sessionKey=: not found
./router.sh: 6: ./router.sh: http://192.168.0.1/RgSetup.asp: not found
Can't open echo: No such file or directory.
Can't open Issue reboot...
(): No such file or directory.
Can't open curl: No such file or directory.
Can't open http://192.168.0.1/goform/RgSetup?sessionKey=: No such file or directory.
Can't open -H: No such file or directory.
Can't open Referer: http://192.168.0.1/RgSetup.asp: No such file or directory.
Can't open --data: No such file or directory.
Can't open WanLeaseAction=0&ApplyRgSetupAction=0&RebootAction=1: No such file or directory.
Can't open exit: No such file or directory.
Can't open 1: No such file or directory.
root@orangepizero:~#
```

I've tried:

- `chmod +x router.sh`
- `apt-get upgrade`
- reinstalling `curl`

I think I'm missing some component, that would explain why did this run on Ubuntu server.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Script needs to be properly formatted. At least, add semi-colon at the end of each command.

Comment: Now it works! Thanks for the tip. [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/dD5rdpNQ)